# Android Studio Bumblebee - device manager not opening

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

I just updated Android Studio to:
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744, built on January 19, 2022

But now I cannot open the device manager anymore.

If I click on the icon, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: How silly this bug is.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems that on Issue Tracker of Google other people have that issue about device manager after updating to bumblebee.
Probably Google have to fix it with an update:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=device%20manager

**UPDATE:**

I found a workaround: You should press shift 2 times to open search everything and type "Virtual Device Manager". This way you can open it

Comment: I found a workaround:
You should press shift 2 times to open search everything and type "Virtual Device Manager".
This way you can open it

Comment: Thanks for that workaround. It's really helpful for now.

Comment: @DavidS. Hero of the day!

Comment: Thanks @DavidS.! This worked like a charm. I thought the AVD got borked after the update.

Comment: @DavidS. legend thanks

Comment: @DavidS. you should add the workaround to your answer

Answer (score 12):

If you are using project for Flutter, Please follow below:
`File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Project Settings` -> `Modules` -> `Add` -> `Android` -> `Ok`

[image]

Comment: Works perfect. Although this seems to be a bug as also stated by others in this thread, this is the correct answer that makes the button work for now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to click the option menu while opening the android Studio Please follow the screen shot[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are still experiencing this issue in the latest version(Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch1), click on the search icon in Android Studio and type "virtual device manager".

See attached screenshots.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and updating it 2021.1.1 patch 3 to the latest android studio version fixed that issue for me.