# I need help opening my device manager in android studio on my mac m1

Tags: android

I just recently updated android studio to bumblebee 2021.1.1
and now when I try to click and open the device manager (located in the top right hand corner) it does not respond at all. NO error code no nothing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi5jP.png)

Comment: Facing the same issue in Mac

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855621/android-studio-bumblebee-device-manager-not-opening
same issue - with workaround

Comment: I have a similar problem and pass this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855621/android-studio-bumblebee-device-manager-not-opening/71059336#71059336

Answer (score 4):

this happened to me too. I found the answer in this thread  [Android Studio Bumblebee - device manager not opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855621/android-studio-bumblebee-device-manager-not-opening)   press shift key twice to open search everywhere and type virtual device manager. That will let you launch it. It's kludgy but works